# Adding variable in Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I have this shortcode `[post color="XYZ" width="980" height="610]`

I wish to pass $color in color="". Here, $color is fetched from dynamic URL: [www.mydomain.com/check/?color=BLUE](http://www.mydomain.com/check/?color=BLUE) $color is working fine otherwise, but I wish to pass it in the shortcode so that color is dynamically loaded on the page based on $color

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want this parameter to come from the shortcode or the URL? What does your current shortcode code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the variable contents in to the shortcode, you would probably be better to pass in the URL parameter you are setting, i.e. `[post color="color" width="980" heigh="610"]`. Because your shortcode will execute during load in PHP, you can then tell your shortcode function to store the value of `$_GET['color']` to later use in that function.

You might do this like:

```
function build_the_thing( $atts ) {
    $pageColorURL = $_GET[$atts['color']];
    return $pageColorURL;
}
add_shortcode( 'post', 'build_the_thing' );
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `$_GET` in your code. See filter_input https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php